# Specify key when running a task as a user with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to perform an ansible task as a specific user, one whom I have just set up. I have a playbook similar to this:

```
- name: create my user
  become: yes
  user:
    name: "{{my_user}}"
    state: present

- name: Add public key to my user's authorized_keys
  become: yes
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{my_user}}"
    key: "{{lookup('file', playbook_dir + '/assets/id.pub')}}"

- name: update my user path
  remote_user: "{{my_user}}"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/home/{{my_user}}/.bash_profile"
    line: "export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar/bin"
    create: yes
```

The problem is, when I get to the third task and I attempt to do the command as `my_user`, I get a `Permission denied` error. I assume that this error comes from the fact that the SSH key is not valid to log in as that user. I tried adding a `private_key_file` argument in addition to the `remote_user` argument, but that got me an error. Is there any way to change the SSH key file when logging in as a particular user? It almost seems worthless to be able to change the user on a per-task basis, if you can't choose which SSH key to use. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are can be root on the server, which you should since you are using `become: true`, you should be able to become any other user and bypass using `remote_user` and setting up ssh keys on your local machine. The third task would read:

```
- name: update my user path
  become: true
  become_user: "{{my_user}}"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/home/{{my_user}}/.bash_profile"
    line: "export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar/bin"
    create: yes
```

Comment: Well the thing is that I ultimately want to separate out the tasks where I'm becoming `remote_user` into their own module, so I can use them on a machine where I don't necessarily have sudo access.